# How to force nuxt to generate html not in one line

Tags: vue.js, server-side-rendering, nuxt.js

npm run generate creates html-files from pages folder and all of these html-files contains single string code in body tag. How do I fix it? I know that the problem isn't {html: minify...} in nuxt.config.js

Thank you in advance!

nuxt.config.js

```
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {    
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: "all"
    }
  },

  plugins: [{ src: '~/plugins/main', ssr: false }],

  css: ["~assets/main.scss"],

  modules: ['@nuxtjs/style-resources'],

  styleResources: {scss: "~assets/variables.scss"},

  head: {
    title: 'Test',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'Optinum' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },

  loading: { color: '#3B8070' },

  build: {
    // html {minify...} doesn't work for html in body tag   
    extractCSS: true,

    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
        "window.jQuery": "jquery"
      })
    ],

    extend (config, { isDev, isClient }) {
      if (isDev && isClient) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /(node_modules)/
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your `Nuxt` config?

Comment: I added it to the question.